# How to set click event for datepicker in android

Tags: android-datepicker

I've just created default datepicker from the link http://www.androidpeople.com/android-datepicker-dialog-example .Its working fine.But my problem is when i click date button.,it shown up..and i change the date and click cancel button on date alert.Again when i click date button.,it should shown current date..not previously changed date.  i.e.i just need to get current date at each click whatever the date change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solve method may be not the better:when you call OnDateSetListener(),you should save the first date,so when you chick the cancen button,you shululd recover it